# Funcion group by sobre columna tipo varchar no funciona

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Tengo una consulta en la cual cuento las filas agrupadas por un código tipo varchar debería contar 1 pero cuenta las 3, podrian ver que esta mal

la columna agrupada es ID_CURSO_UNICO

```
           SELECT count(ID_CURSO_UNICO) as cantidad from encuesta_apl where
           YEAR(fecha)=? and ID_ENCUESTA=? group by ID_CURSO_UNICO
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el resultado que da
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por supuesto que cuenta 3, por que `COUNT()` actúa sobre los datos desagregados y efectivamente hay 3 registros. Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

La forma más explicativa, sería contar los grupos:

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
       FROM (SELECT ID_CURSO_UNICO 
                    from encuesta_apl 
                    where YEAR(fecha)=? and ID_ENCUESTA=? 
                    group by ID_CURSO_UNICO)
```

Pero la más sencilla:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT ID_CURSO_UNICO) as cantidad 
       from encuesta_apl where
       YEAR(fecha)=? and ID_ENCUESTA=?
```

Answer (score 1):

La solución más general cuando tu tabla tenga muchos registros recomiendo que consideres obtener cuantas ocurrencias tendrá cada valor del dato ID_CURSO_UNICO y el SQL adecuado seria

```
 SELECT ID_CURSO_UNICO as curso, count(1) as cantidad 
from encuesta_apl 
where YEAR(fecha)=? and ID_ENCUESTA=? 
group by ID_CURSO_UNICO
```

y si quieres saber solo los que tenga mas de una ocurrencia en la tabla complementa con Having quedando en:

```
 SELECT ID_CURSO_UNICO as curso, count(1) as cantidad 
from encuesta_apl 
where YEAR(fecha)=? and ID_ENCUESTA=? 
group by ID_CURSO_UNICO
having count(1) >= 2
```

Comment: Si quieres dar formato al código a la hora de escribir una respuesta, puedes seleccionarlo y dar click sobre la opción `{}` que se encuentra en la parte superior del cuadro de texto. O usando el atajo de teclado `Ctrl+K`.